# Undefined method size for nil:NilClass in gem install

Tags: ruby, rubygems, vagrant, bundler

Running VMWare Fusion 6 on a Mac 10.8.5. Tried to install the vagrant-vmware-fusion plugin and got this error. I think this is a ruby issue but I'm not really sure as I have no experience using Ruby. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-vmware-fusion
Installing the 'vagrant-vmware-fusion' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_reader/entry.rb:127:in `read': undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_reader/entry.rb:126:in `read'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_reader/entry.rb:126:in `read'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/format.rb:73:in `block (2 levels) in from_io'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_reader.rb:64:in `block in each'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_reader.rb:55:in `loop'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_reader.rb:55:in `each'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_input.rb:138:in `block (2 levels) in each'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_reader.rb:28:in `new'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_input.rb:137:in `block in each'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_reader.rb:64:in `block in each'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_reader.rb:55:in `loop'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_reader.rb:55:in `each'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_input.rb:132:in `each'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/format.rb:66:in `block in from_io'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_input.rb:22:in `open'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package.rb:44:in `open'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/format.rb:62:in `from_io'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/format.rb:46:in `block in from_file_by_path'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/format.rb:45:in `open'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/format.rb:45:in `from_file_by_path'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:119:in `format'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:129:in `spec'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:386:in `ensure_required_ruby_version_met'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:156:in `install'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:297:in `block in install'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:270:in `each'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:270:in `each_with_index'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:270:in `install'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/commands/plugin/action/install_gem.rb:49:in `block in call'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/commands/plugin/gem_helper.rb:42:in `block in with_environment'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:40:in `use_ui'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/commands/plugin/gem_helper.rb:41:in `with_environment'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/commands/plugin/action/install_gem.rb:39:in `call'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/commands/plugin/action/bundler_check.rb:20:in `call'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:61:in `block in run'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:61:in `run'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/commands/plugin/command/base.rb:17:in `action'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/commands/plugin/command/install.rb:27:in `execute'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/commands/plugin/command/root.rb:52:in `execute'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:38:in `execute'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:478:in `cli'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/bin/vagrant:96:in `<top (required)>'
from /Applications/Vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/bin/vagrant:23:in `load'
from /Applications/Vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/bin/vagrant:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: stackoverflow.com is for programming questions. You might get a better answers on http://superuser.com/

Comment: Possibly the downloaded gem is corrupted. Try to remove it from ~/.vagrant.d/gems/gems and retry.

Comment: Contact support. You've bought it together with the plugin. Mitchell is (acc to my experience) very responsive

Comment: @benatespina Thank you I will try posting the question there.

Comment: @Emyl I've tried removing the corrupted gem and replacing it. Unfortunately it did not work. Will try again though.

Comment: @StephenKing I have. Mitchell stated the same answer as Emyl. And suggested that perhaps I was behind a proxy. So I tried uninstalling and redownloading the .dmg file via a different internet connection. Which did not work.

Comment: `tar_reader` exception is about corrupted download. Delete .../cache/vagrant...gem and try again.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is that the said other people above: the gem package is broken, you need get a proper package from an internet source, then just install it. [Here](https://github.com/wvanbergen/chunky_png/issues/37) is the similar problem and gem author advises just to update the gem:

> The error seems to occur during the "untarring" of the gem package. That seems to indicate that the package file it tries to untar is corrupt. Given that the untar source code hasn't changed in 2 years in rubygems, and it works fine for everybody else, the problem is specific to your install.
>
> In your case, all other gems work fine, so only this file is corrupt. I assume something went wrong during the download/unzip that corrupted the file. It probably has stored this corrupted file somewhere. You may need to figure out where it is so you can delete it. Afterwards, rubygems should attempt to download it again, after which the install should work as expected

So as the people adviced remove all the cachged package:

```
$ find -name "package.gem" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Then download the gem somewhere you have a good internet line:

```
$ gem fetch package.gem
```

Copy the gem into the source project folder, and then install it:

```
$ gem install ./package.gem
```

If it is successfully installed copy it to bundler cache (in my case it resided in `.bundle` folder), so:

```
$ mv ./package.gem ./.bundle/cache/
```

Then issue `bundle`:

```
$ bundle
```